# SWF only working in debug folder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

If I copy all the files from the debug folder and paste it somewhere it stops working gives me a sandbox error. ( I am not using any absolute paths) and everything seems to be fine in debug folder. Any Ideas?

It's a actionscript project in flex builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the new path to your Flash Player trust file.

Answer (score 3):

This may help: http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2008/06/the_security_sandbox_in_flex_b.html